# ps command in MKS Toolkit list nothing when run the batch file from Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, mks

I created a batch file as below:

```
set VAR1=VALUE1
start another_batch_file
sleep 10
ps -l |grep abc > foo.txt
```

another_batch_file would start several processes, I want to use ps to list some specific ones. This script works well when I run it from a cmd window, although if I create a task in Task Scheduler to call this script automatically the foo.txt will be empty.

I also tried to output the `ps -l` result to a file, it's also empty

ps & grep both from MKS toolkit.

**Edit:**

Per the comments, I have tried with the script similar to the following:

```
set VAR1=VALUE1
start another_batch_file
sleep 10
ps > foo.txt
tasklist > bar.txt
```

Now foo.txt is still empty, while bar.txt has normal output which contains all the processes' information.

Any one has a clue?

**Edit 2:**

I have the box "Run with highest privileges" checked and the the `ps` command works well now.

I have been using the same user account when run the script in a cmd window or by a scheduled task, although the `ps` exeutable file located in a mapped drive, I think this caused the script needs higher privileges to run

Comment: I suppose that `grep abc` searches for `another_batch_file`?

Comment: yes, in fact cmd is one of my grep target, I just don't know why the foo.txt file is empty in Task Scheduler case

Comment: If it's empty, then remove the `grep` part, to see what the output is and how you should create the best grep expression for it

Comment: I have tried to output the result of `ps -l`, it's also empty, I have edit the questioni about this, thank for reminding this

Comment: Do you get any output from `ps`? Can you redirect it to a file from the command line?

Comment: I have tried and it's also empty

Comment: And what is the output of `ps` without redirection?

Comment: I don't know how to get the output without redirect to a file when run this script from Task Scheduler, I run this script from a cmd window and out put of ps is normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works at the prompt:  task scheduler runs in the system account by default and has no access to network resources, and if your other batch file is trying to access them then it will not load.

Answer (score 2):

A batch file isn't never in the process list. Batch files are executed by cmd.exe, so cmd.exe is in the list.

But you should be able to access it with `ps`, if you add a switch for displaying the parameters, too.

It's also possible with `tasklist`.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /V | grep another_batch_file
```

> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - another_batch_file.bat cmd.exe
>   1320 Console                    1         3.132 K Unknown